# Worklight: adapter is deleted when accessing another app's WL console in the same server

Tags: push, ibm-mobilefirst

Recently, I am working on the WL Push notification feature. I find a strange issue.

I deployed two applications (Sush as: AppOne and AppTwo) into the same server. So, I can access their consoles by http://xxx.x.x.xxx/AppOne/console or http://xxx.x.x.xxx/AppTwo/console. I added the WL Push feature into AppTwo project (some changes for PushAdapter, SecurityTest, authenticationConfig, etc). It can be said that AppTwo is just the same as WL PushDemo app.

Everything is fine with AppTwo including Push functionality. But when I access the WL console of AppOne, the issue is coming to me. **The PushAdapter of AppTwo is deleted**. I read the logs which said something like:

"Security Test defined in createEventSource not specified in authenticationConfig.xml...
PushAdapter deleted..."

At this time, if I access the WL console of AppTwo and deploy the PushAdapter again, it is always failed to do it. It will work only if I restart the WL server. Is it a defect?

Worklight 6.0.0.2

Comment: Download the latest iFix from IBM Fix Central. Should be resolved. Download and install both Server and Studio components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds very much like a known and fixed defect (APAR PI13334) in Worklight 6.0.0.x.

My suggestion is to login to [IBM Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/), [download the latest available Worklight 6.0.0.2 iFix](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20Worklight%20Consumer%20Edition&release=6.0.0.2&platform=Windows&function=all) (July 17th, 2014) and verify this is resolved for you. There is no local workaround.